# Client to client communication over GAE

Tags: android, google-app-engine, jakarta-ee

I consider use GAE as server to communicate Android phone with thin client.
My typical use scenario is:
User opens web page (GAE) and request some info from remote device
Device gets message, and sends it back to user through web page.

Sending messages to phone is piece of cake thanks to GCM.
Hard part is return response to user.
The only one idea I have is inserting response to datastore, then it query repetitively, But there are some disadvantages: delay in the communication and excessive usage of the datastore and it's quotas.

I have heard and read about channels API, but when I when using GAE there is strong possibility, that both clients will connect to different machines. Have you any ideas how to do this the right way?

To make my question more clear:
Let's simplify problem. I have one servlet taking message from android client. Message is addressed to user logged in with GWT and another servlet and having it's own session instance.
Have you any idea how to pass message from one servlet to other?
As far as I know, there is no possibly to have it done by some automatic sendMessage() method.
I just need to implement some kind of mailbox. At this moment I see memcache in this role. Perfect for it should be some service like amazon sms, but having my app dispatched between many servers makes me a bit unhappy.
Queues are other idea, but not those from GAE. I don't want solutions labeled as experimental in production environment.

Comment: Single messages are limited to 32K in the channel API so probably not the best fit.

Comment: 32K is enough, but how to find the right channel?

Comment: ah, I see. different machines as in difference instances. Well, it does not really matter if you know their ID via a session or otherwise as that's what you use to send the message, it's not specific to an instance. If 32k is enough then memcache should be all you need, and you can query that often. Try that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Channel API is your answer.  Every browser instance should open a channel, which is identified by a token.  It's up to you to keep track of all the tokens, probably in some sort of session data.  Then you can send messages to the appropriate browser.

So far I've noticed sometimes messages fail to send.  Not often, but sometimes.  If the contents of your message aren't vital, it might be ok.  In my case, I built a backup polling HTTP query.  The benefit of the channel is that the backup polling doesn't need to be super frequent for me.

Comment: Channel API is not available on Android, as Channel API lib is javascript only. There are hackish wrappers that embed WebView, but this is IMO overkill.

Comment: Android part is easy with GCM. Hard part is how to find right session in multi instances environment. Is something like application bean possible?

Comment: memcache is shared around all instances - all instances see memcache identically so it does not matter what instance "asks" memcache as they are all sharing the same memcache pool.

Comment: I thought the piotrpo was asking about some sort of web "thin client".  If the question is about how to store the GCM registration ID, then you need to use the datastore.  Memcache values will disappear randomly.  What you really should do is store it in the datastore, but cache it in memcache, and fall back to the datastore if it's not found in memcache.  Luckily, the datastore ndb API will do that for you if you get entities by key.

Answer (score 1):

try Channel API is good and reliable, we are using in one of the our app [MobiTexter](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.mobitexter&hl=en) and so far havn't faced even a single problem.